# How to use a UIProgressView with UITextField as the progress value?

Tags: swift, uiprogressview

My goal is to create a UIProgressView that shows the progress that the user enters in. I have been looking for examples everywhere and all of them use the progress view with a timer. I also want the progress to be saved using User Defaults. Is there a way to do it where the user enters in the values? If so, can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
    progressView.progress = (sender as AnyObject).value
```

Comment: Where does the user enter the value (or values, I guess...since it's a measure of "progress")?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a computedProperty like this in your viewController:

```
var progress: Float? {
    set{
        guard let value = newValue else {
            UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "progress")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
            progressView.progress = 0
            return
        }
        progressView.progress = value
        UserDefaults.standard.set(value, forKey: "progress")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
    get{
        return UserDefaults.standard.float(forKey: "progress") ?? 0.0
    }
}
```

When you want to set the saved progress you can do:

```
progressView.progress = self.progress
```

When you want to set it from a textField:

```
self.progress = (Float(textField.text ?? "") ?? 0.0)/100
```

This way you are saving it in UserDefalts also

Answer (score 0):

`UIProgressView.progress` expects a Float value between 0.0 and 1.0.

You have to convert your UITextField string value to a Float value, like so:

```
let textField = sender as? UITextField
if let value = Float(textField?.text ?? ""), value >= 0 && value <= 1.0 {
    progressView.progress = value
}
```

If you expect a value between 0-100 in textField, use this instead:

```
if let value = Int(textField?.text ?? ""), (0...100).contains(value) {
    progressView.progress = Float(value / 100)
}
```

To save `value` to UserDefaults, use this:

```
UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "progressValue")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

And retrieve from UserDefaults:

```
let value = UserDefaults.standard.float(forKey: "progressValue") ?? 0
```